# libspotify playlist update latency

Tags: c, spotify

We're using libspotify to update playlists that we have generated against a single account that need to be kept up to date over time.  We're using a fork of the spotify-api-server to do this https://github.com/tom-martin/spotify-api-server

After sending an update to a playlist's tracks using libspotify we generally wait for the callback that we passed to sp_playlist_add_callbacks to be called before we report a success to the user.  Often this callback arrives within a suitable time frame but increasingly we're getting unacceptable delays in receiving this callback.  Sometimes 30 seconds, sometimes even longer, sometimes minutes, sometimes hours.  It seems that generally these delays are caused by libspotify pausing for a period and not calling any callbacks until it seemingly "unfreezes" and calls all the backed up callbacks in quick succession.

Is it reasonable to use this callback as an indicator of a successful playlist update?  Is there any obvious reason for these long delays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you correctly handling the `notify_main_thread` function to keep libSpotify running?

Also, sometimes the playlist system gets backed up, goes down or otherwise takes a while to respond to requests. Our own clients keep their own cache of what the playlist tree should look like once pending transactions are successful to keep the UI snappy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Pretty sure we're using notify_main_thread properly yes.  We don't really have the luxury of a local cache as this is happening on our servers.  We can't do this in the client as we're producing a playlist for the user with a different spotify account so that we can share it with other users and keep it up to date.

Comment: By "correctly handling the `notify_main_thread`" you mean the loop in the main thread, or there is something to call manually sometimes ?